# Debug my AppsScript add-on with full permissions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

Previously to test my AppsScript add-on for Sheets, I could connect it to a Google Sheets spreadsheet,on using `Run → Test as Add-on`, and then I could press the run or debug buttons [image], and the chosen function would run and stop at breakpoints.

However recently, maybe since I moved my add-on into a [standard GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project), any attempt to run or debug functions from the AppsScript IDE gives me the error `Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context`.

Based on [the docs](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#editor_add-on_authorization), I realise that normally I shouldn't be able to call `getUi()` from outside of a trigger, but how can I debug my add-on without being able to do this? Is there a mode I can enable that will give me full access to test my add-on with full permissions?

Comment: Have you been through the [Create a test configuration](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons#create_a_test_configuration) steps?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You can test your addon from the `Run > Test as add-on` menu item after creating a test configuration.*

#### More Information:

From the [Test an editor add-on documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons):

> A test configuration is the combination of an add-on and a test document. Once you have a script version developed and would like to test it as an add-on, follow these steps:
>
> 1. If you do not have one already, create a sheet, doc, presentation, or form to test the add-on with. If desired, format and fill the doc with data for the add-on to operate on.
> 2. Open the script project containing your add-on in the script editor.
> 3. (Optional) You may wish to [save a new version](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/versions) of your project by selecting **File > Manage versions**, then **Save New Version**. Close the **Manage Versions** dialog.
> 4. Select **Run > Test as add-on**.
> 5. In the **Select version** box, choose a code version or select "Test with latest code".
> 6. In the **Installation Config** box, select the initial [authorization](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#installed_versus_enabled) state for the test.
> 7. Click the **Select Doc** button. This brings up a file select dialog. Find the test Sheet, Doc, Slides presentation, or Form you want to test the add-on on, click it, and then click **Select** to close the dialog.
> 8. Click **Save** to save the test configuration.

And then, you can [run the test configuration](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons#run_a_test_configuration):

> If you have one or more saved test configurations, you can run one of them by following these steps:
>
> 1. Open the script project containing your add-on in the script editor.
> 2. Select **Run > Test as add-on**.
> 3. Under **Execute Saved Test**, find the test to execute and select it. Click **Test**.
>
> At this point the Google Sheet, Doc, Slides presentation, or Form specified in the test configuration opens in a new tab (this document view is referred to as the "add-on preview document"). The add-on is in the authorization state specified in test configuration. You can now verify that the add-on functions as intended for the test document by interacting with its menu and UI elements.

You can read more about this in the references below.

#### References:

- [Testing an editor add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons)
- [Versions | Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/versions)
- [Editor add-on authorization - Installed versus enabled](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#installed_versus_enabled)

Comment: This process is what I'm doing, and I am able to run my app's functions in the test document, but since it's the editor that's triggering these functions not the user, I'm unable to access the UI functions, and I get the error above.

Comment: Can you provide the code where `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` is being called from? I have had no issue in my test environment testing an add-on that is connected to a GCP project, so this would help debugging. Of course, sanitise your code first.